# Let $H,K\le G$, abelian $G$, and let $\phi:G\to H$ be a hom. s.t. 1) $\phi(h)=h\forall h\in H$, 2) $\text{Ker }\phi=K$. Show $G=H\oplus K$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, direct-product

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of an Abelian group $G$ and let $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism such that
>
> 1. $\phi(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$.
> 2. $\text{Ker }\phi=K$.
>
> Show that $G=H\oplus K$
>
> Hint:  for all $x\in G$ consider $x-\phi(x)$.

I am thinking of letting $\phi(h)=h+K$, then as the identity for the coset element $h+K$ is $K$, which satisfies $(2)$. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

The conclusion of the question requires me to show $G$ can be written as a direct sum $x=h+k$ for $x\in G$, $h\in H$, $k\in K$ and also show that $H\cap K=\{0\}$.   I think I am suppose to use the hint somehow to conclude that $x=h+k$.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can proceed further into the question?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:  Since the book the question is from is not a popular one, I am including the relevant definitions, theorems and corollary from the section chapter where the question is from:

Definition:  Let $H_1, H_2, \ldots H_n$ be subgroups of an Abelian group $G$.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} H_i$ is called a direct sum and is written $\oplus_{i=1}^{n} H_i$ if for every $x\in \sum_{i=1}^{n} H_i$, we have $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} h_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} h'_i$ with $h_i, h'_i \in H_i$ if and only if $h_i=h'_i$ for all $i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Theorem 1:  Let $G$ be an Abelian group and $H_1, H_2, \ldots H_n$ be subgroups of $G$.  Then the following statements are equivalent:

$(1)$  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} H_i$ is a direct sum.   
$(2)$  $(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} H_i + \sum_{i=j+1}^{n} H_i)\cap H_j=\{0\}$  
$(3)$  $(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} H_i)\cap H_j=\{0\}$  
$(4)$  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} h_i=0$ where $h_i \in H_i$ for all $i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, implies $h_i=0$ for all $i$, $1\leq i \leq n$.

Corollary: Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that

$(1)$ $H\cap K=\{0\} $   
$(2)$  $|H+K|=|G|$    
Then $G=H\oplus K\cong H\times K$

Theorem 2:  Let $G$ be an Abelian group such that $G=\oplus_{i=1}^{n} H_i.$  Then $G=\times_{i=1}^{n} H_i$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139107/discussion-on-question-by-seth-mai-let-h-k-le-g-abelian-g-and-let-phig).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in G$. Since $\phi:G\to H$, know that $\phi(x)\in H$ so we can think of $\phi$ as extracting an $H$-content of $x$. Then $\phi(\phi(x))=\phi(x)$ because $\phi$ is identity on $H$. This is the intuition for the element $y=x-\phi(x)$ of the hint, since $\phi(y)=0$ and hence $y\in K$.

Then $x=\phi(x)+x-\phi(x)$ is in $H+K$. Now we have to show that the sum is direct. Let $z\in H\cap K$. Then $\phi(z)=0$  since $z\in K$ and $\phi(z)=z$ since $z\in H$. Thus $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is done in three steps:

- $H,K\unlhd G$ since each subgroup of an abelian group is normal.
- Let $g\in H\cap K$. Since $g\in H$, we have $\phi(g)=g$, but $g\in K$, so $0=\phi(g)=g$. Thus $H\cap K=\{0\}$.
- We have $$H+K=\{ h+k\in G\mid h\in H, k\in K\}\subseteq G.$$ Let $g\in G$. Consider $f=\phi(g-\phi(g))$. We know $\phi(g)\in H$ by definition of $\phi$. Then $$\begin{align}f&=\phi(g)-\phi(\phi(g))\\ &=\phi(g)-\phi(g)\\ &=0;\end{align}$$ therefore, $g-\phi(g)\in \ker(\phi)=K$, meaning $$g=\phi(g)+(g-\phi(g))\in H+K,$$ so $G\subseteq H+K$; thus $G=H+K$.

Hence $G=H\oplus K\cong H\times K$ by Theorem 2.

Comment: isn't the way $\phi$ is defined in effect makes it a projection operator.  If $x=h+k$, then $\phi(x)=\phi(h+k)=\phi(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$ and $\phi(h+k)=0$ implies that $k\in \text{ker }\phi=K$, and this is true for all $k\in K$.

Comment: No, @SethMai. Haven't you already got $k\in K$ by definition?

Comment: sorry for the lengthy back and forth between Arthuro, the fact that $\phi$ sends $G$ to $H$ with $\phi(h)=h$ makes me wonder what happens to all the elements that are in $G - H$.  I thought the question ask me to take into that into account along with the two given properties.  As a result, I thought I need to figure out how to write out what $\phi$ is suppose to be.

Comment: It doesn't ask you to, @SethMai, so, *a priori*, no.

Comment: if $\phi(h+k)=0$, and $\phi(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$, then $\phi(h+k)=h=0$ iff $\phi(0+k)=\phi(k)=0$, for all $k\in K$ Hence $k\in \text{ker }\phi$.

Comment: How are you defining $k$, @SethMai?

Comment: I am letting $x=h+k$ where $x\in G$ and $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ and $G=H+K$, at this point, I am not claiming that $G=H\oplus K$ which is why I am wondering if $\phi$ is a projection map?

Comment: But $K$ is *defined* to be $\ker(\phi)$, @SethMai.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: It might help to ask a new question, @SethMai, rather than rely on inappropriate use of comments.

Comment: but don't the way I defined K includes the case that $K=\text{ker }\phi$?.  As Erik Kofoed show in his answer $0\in \text{ker }\phi=K$

Comment: I will ask a separate question about whether $\phi$ can be interpreted as a projection map.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I try to up vote your answer, but when i do, it gives a -1.  If I pressed the down vote, it gives a -2.

Comment: That means you have already voted up, @SethMai.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  The short exact sequence $$1\to K\hookrightarrow G\overset{\phi}{\to }H\to1$$ is [left split](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma).  The morphism $\psi:G\to K$ being $\psi(x)=x-\phi(x)$.