# If $\phi(\phi(g))=g$ then show that $G\cong \phi(G) \times \text{ker }\phi$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

[image]

Can someone please check over the correctness of my solution for the following question:

> Let $G$ be an Abelian group and $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ a homomorphism such that $\phi(\phi(g))=g$ for all $g\in G$. (such a homomorphism is called a $\textbf{projection}$ homomorphism) Show that $G\cong \phi(G) \times \text{ker }\phi$.
> Hint: consider for all $g\in G$, $g-\phi(g)$  [or in direct product notation: $g\phi^{-1}(g)$]

The question came from the same source as the following question in this post:  [Show $G=H\oplus K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528212/let-h-k-le-g-abelian-g-and-let-phig-to-h-be-a-hom-s-t-1-phih-h/4528590?noredirect=1#comment9516857_4528590). The relevant definitions and theorems assumed will be the same as that post therein.

As suggested in the hint let $y=g(\phi(g))^{-1}$, then $\phi(y)=\phi(g(\phi(g))^{-1})=\phi(g)\phi((\phi(g))^{-1})=\phi(g)(\phi(\phi(g)))^{-1}=\phi(g)g^{-1}$, because $\phi$ is a homomorphism and $(\phi(g))^{-1}=\phi(g^{-1})$.

Let $g\in \text{ker }\phi$ implies $\phi(g)=e$ and $\phi(\phi(g))=g=\phi(e)=e$, and so $g=e$, this means that $\text{ker }\phi=\{e\}$ and so $\phi$ is injective.

Since $\phi$ is one to one, $\phi(\phi(g)g^{-1})=e$ then $\phi(\phi(g)g^{-1})\in \text{ker }\phi$, and $G$ is abelian, $g\phi(g^{-1})=g(\phi(g))^{-1}=e.$ Which also gives $\phi(g)=g$ for all $g\in G$.  Hence $\phi$ is the identity map on all of $G$.

Also $g\in \phi(G)$, then $\phi(g)=g$.  Since $\phi(\phi(g))=\phi(g)=g=e$, then $g\in \phi(G) \cap \text{ker }\phi={e}.$  Lastly, $g=g(\phi(g))^{-1}g$, because $g=\phi(g)=\phi(g((\phi(g))^{-1})g=\phi(g)\phi((\phi(g))^{-1})\phi(g)=\phi(g)\phi(\phi(g^{-1}))\phi(g)=(gg^{-1})g.$ As $\phi(g)\phi((\phi(g))^{-1})\in \text{ker }\phi$ and $\phi(g)\in \phi(G)$, and $\text{ker }\phi\cdot \phi(G)=G.$  We can conclude that $\phi(G)\times\text{ker }\phi \cong G$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your definition of a projection is incorrect; the condition is $\phi(\phi(g)) = \phi(g)$, or more simply $\phi^2 = \phi$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am reproducing the question verbatim from the textbook.  I will grab a screenshot of it.

Comment: As written it's incorrect, then; that's probably a typo.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added the screen shot.  I can included a screen shot of the previous similarly sounding question for the previous exercise if that will make it more clear.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan assuming if we disregard whether the condition of the question is incorrect in terms of correct definitional naming, is the question still correct?

Comment: If $\phi(\phi(g))=g$, the $\phi$ is invertible, so $Ker(\phi)=\{0\}$ and $\phi(G)=G$, so the question would be trivial. As Qiaochu Yuan explained, there is a typo in the problem.

Comment: @Taladris I grabbed a different screenshot of also the previous problem. The problems in the text are extremely similar.

Comment: @Taladris can you explain how $\phi(\phi(g))=g$ implies that $\phi$ is invertible please.  I mean don't you have to show that $\text{ker }\phi=\{e\}$ first, also, I am not sure how to show the surjectivity of $\phi$ given the definition of $\phi(\phi(g))=g$.  Another thing is, I thought for this question, i had to show that the definition satisfies something similar to condition $(1)$ in the previous one.

Comment: $\phi(\phi(g))=g$ for every $g$ in $G$ means that $\phi \circ \phi=id_G$ (where $id_G$ is the identity on $G$), so $\phi^{-1}=\phi$.

Comment: You can also show surjectivity and injectivity easily: if $h=\phi(g)$, then $\phi(h)=\phi(\phi(g))=g$, so $\phi$ is surjective. And if $\phi(g)=e$, then $g=\phi(\phi(g))=\phi(e)=e$ (since $\phi$ is a homomorphism), so $Ker(\phi)=\{ e\}$.

Comment: @Taladris thank you so much for your explanations.

Comment: "because $\phi$ is a homomorphism and $\phi^{-1}(g)=\phi(g^{-1})$" That's not true in general. You are confusing $\phi(g)^{-1}$, the inverse in the group $G$ of the element $\phi(g)$ (which always exists) with $\phi^{-1}(g)$, the inverse function (which has no reason to exist if $\phi$ is only a homomorphism) of $\phi$ applied to $g$. Note that you use the inverse function $\phi$ **before** proving it is injective.

Comment: @Taladris I edited the post accordingly.